# Median of Two Sorted Arrays - Problem Solution Working in Python But not in C++

Tags: c++, python-3.x, casting

I am trying to solve the leet code problem No. 4 [Median of Two Sorted Arrays](https://leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/description/). I have coded a solution in Python3 that is working fine and accepted. The code is:

```
class Solution:
    def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1:list[int], nums2:list[int])->float:
        A, B = nums1, nums2
        total = len(A) + len(B)
        half = total // 2

        if len(B) < len(A):
            A, B = B, A
        l, r = 0, len(A) - 1
        while True:
            i = (l+r) // 2
            j = half - i -2 

            Aleft = A[i] if i>=0 else float("-infinity")
            Aright = A[i+1] if (i+1) < len(A) else float("infinity")
            Bleft = B[j] if j >=0 else float("-infinity")
            Bright = B[j+1] if (j+1) < len(B) else float("infinity")

            #partition if right
            if Aleft <= Bright and Bleft <= Aright:
                #if even
                if total % 2:
                    return min (Aright, Bright)
                #if odd
                else:
                    return (max(Aleft, Bleft) + min(Aright, Bright)) / 2
            elif Aleft > Bright:
                r = i - 1
            else:
                l = i+1
```

When I try to apply the same logic with C++ code, it is stuck in an infinite loop for the input nums1 = [1,3], nums2 = [2]. The C++ code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    double findMedianSortedArrays(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2) {
        vector<int> A = nums1;
        vector<int> B = nums2;
        int total = A.size() + B.size();
        int half = total / 2;
        if (B.size() < A.size()) {
            A.swap(B);
        }
        int l = 0;
        int r = A.size() - 1;
        while (true) {
            int i = (l + r) / 2;
            int j = half - i - 2;
            cout << i << endl;
            int Aleft = (i >= 0) ? A[i] : INT_MIN;
            int Aright = ((i + 1) < A.size()) ? A[i + 1] : INT_MAX;
            int Bleft = (j >= 0) ? B[j] : INT_MIN;
            int Bright = ((j + 1) < B.size()) ? B[j + 1] : INT_MAX;
            cout << Bleft << " " << Bright << endl;
            cout << Aleft << " " << Aright << endl;
            
            if (Aleft <= Bright && Bleft <= Aright) {
                if (total % 2) {
                    return min(Aright, Bright);
                } else {
                    return (max(Aleft, Bleft) + min(Aright, Bright)) / 2.0;
                }
            } else if (Aleft > Bright) {
                r = i - 1;
            } else {
                l = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Solution s;
    vector<int> nums1 = {1, 3};
    vector<int> nums2 = {2};
    cout << s.findMedianSortedArrays(nums1, nums2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There may be an issue with the data type or typecasting. How to solve this issue? Can anyone help, please?

Comment: why yu make copies of array? you can write `double findMedianSortedArrays(vector<int> nums1, vector<int> nums2)` if that's intentional, but it doesn't look so..

Comment: You just can't simply pass code from interpreted dynamically typed language to compiled, statically typed one.  `float("infinity")` is NOT `MAX_INT`. It's a `float` value of IEEE754 infinity. `while(true)` in C++ is a dubios construct.. `pylist` isn't a `vector`.. and on, and on..

Comment: Most likely, you have a negative index somewhere. This is valid (but probably not what you want) in Python, but undefined in C++. Start with looking at `j` as well as `i`.

Comment: [What is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).  Also, the way you "translate" from one computer language to another is to 1) know both computer languages. 2) Understand what language A is doing  3) Throw language A away and implement the solution in language B using language B idioms and best practices.  Line-by-line translations more often than not, do not work.

Comment: Learn how C++ really works first, it is not a language to pickup by trial and error. And it definitely works a lot differently than Python

Comment: 1) `int r = A.size() - 1;` -- Will go haywire if `A` is empty.  2) `int i = (l + r) / 2;` -- This will give unpredicabale results if `l + r` overflows an `int`.  3) `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` -- Use the proper standard headers, not this one.

Answer (score 2):

Not an issue with typecasting, it's an issue with algorithm implementation being wrong.

On very first iteration:

- `l = 0`
- `r = 0` (because `A.size() = 1`)

As a result `i=0`,`j=-1` and stay so (`r = -1` and `l = 0` as well),
because `i = (l+r)/2` always would produce 0: `(0-1)/2` is 0. Python version of code avoids that.

`(Aleft <= Bright && Bleft <= Aright)` -> `(2 <= 1) && (INT_MIN <= INT_MAX)` never would be true.

You're in infinite cycle.

PS. You can reorder references instead of copying arrays:

```
double findMedianSortedArrays(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2)
{
    auto &A = (nums1.size() < nums2.size()) ? nums1 : nums2;
    auto &B = (nums1.size() < nums2.size()) ? nums2 : nums1;
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Swift-Friday Pie already gave you the described reply, I'm going to give you the pinpoint reason.

In C++: (-1)/2 results 0 (upper bound)
In Python: (-1)//2 results -1 (lower bound)

If you really want to resemble the Python solution to your C++ code.
 Just update **line 19**.

From:
int i = (l + r)/2;
To:
**int i = (l+r)>=0?(l + r) / 2:(l+r-1)/2;**

It will resemble your exact python solution. And will be accepted.

Comment: Ooh, Python is indeed lower bound? that explains how that code works, I was confused out of mindby it. Language's desinger was an oddball. I know syntax and wrote text processing scripts in it, but not in such detail.

Comment: Yes, basically integer division should be and is lower bound. But c++ does not handle negetive value properly. Thus for negetive value, ironically it becomes upper bound.

Comment: every computer or other digital calculating device humanity created since 1950s operates that way. Lower bound rounding as default behaviour is a feature of a few interpreted languages, most of them dead or forgotten. Most "modern" languages - C#, Rust, Java do the same thing - `-26 / 5` would be `-5`. I.e. it's effect is of truncation. Assymetric lower bound approach creates mathematical artefacts. If you need somethign else, you got `ceil`, `floor`, `round` and `trunc`